# Geometry aspect of a extreme value problem

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, rational-functions, radicals

In a plain with orthogonal coordinate $XOY$, set point $A(a,a)$, and $P$ is a point in  function $y=\frac{1}{x}$,where $x>0$. If the distance between $P$ and $A$ is $2\sqrt{2}$.Find all $a$ satisfies this condition. ($a \in \Bbb{R}$).

---

I can use distance formula between two point to solve this exercise. 
$$|PA| = \sqrt{\left(x-a\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{x}-a\right)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2a\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+2a^2}$$
 then let $u = x+ \frac{1}{x}$. we have $u \geq 2$. then can be find out that $a = -1$ or $a = \sqrt{10}$ directly.

---

Another approach:

Because we want to find $a$, such that the minimum distant($=2\sqrt{2}$) between $A$ and a point $P$ in function $y=1/x$. So If we set $A$ as the center of a circle ,and radius is $2\sqrt{2}$. this circle is tangent to the function $y=\frac{1}{x}$ at least a point , say $(t, \frac{1}{t})$. then we can get two equations:

$$\begin{cases}\sqrt{(a-t)^2+(a-\frac{1}{t})^2}=2\sqrt{2} & (radius)\\a-t-\frac{1}{t^2}(a-\frac{1}{t})=0 & (tangent)\end{cases} $$

but solve  this equation group (use mathematica) , It is not the same as the first way. what's wrong with me? Please help me . thanks very much.

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo JiangSu province , China. Undergraduate entrance exam 2013.

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740604/find-a-satisfy-an-inequality-for-all-t0 ?

Comment: @Macavity . yes, the same problem. but not the same question.In that post,I try to use distance formula between two points to attack this problem .but failed .following the hint in the comment, I have succeed in solving it. and In this post, I try to use a geometric aspect to observe this question. I think there is no mistake . But this method give a different answer.

Comment: The earlier problem is slightly different - you had an inequality there, and no restriction of $x> 0$, so the solution to that earlier problem is different.  However, I see no difference in the answers for both approaches in **this problem**.  In both approaches I get $(a, t) = (-1, 1), (3, 1), (\sqrt{10}, \sqrt{4\pm\sqrt{15}})$ as the only four solutions.  Maybe you should elaborate where you see a problem.

Comment: Just to visualise the solutions, the points are mapped here http://imgur.com/CJSvzVn - all the coloured segments in the figure have length $2\sqrt2$ and at $P_i$, the tangents are shared by the circles (not drawn) and the graph.

Comment: @Macavity thanks very much. Your answer is right .Following your answer , I have discovered that the two methods are equivalent. thanks very much .